# Do alcoholic "digestives" help digestion?

Tags: nutrition, biology, alcohol

Do [alcoholic digestives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ritif_and_digestif) (e.g. grappa, limoncello, sambuca) really help digestion after a heavy meal?

Comment: Can you provide a source for this claim?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I don't think that really needs a source.  It's part of the description of what a "digestive" is anywhere you care to look.

Comment: @JohnRhoades - Well if it makes you vomit then you could say it helps with digestion by making digestion no longer necessary though I am pretty sure that is not what the OP meant.  I think a good question lurks here but it needs refined.  A source for the claim would go a long way towards doing that and provide us a direction for confirming/refuting.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I thought the name 'digestive' is enough to suggest they are meant to aid digestion. But here's a source: http://www.french-property.com/reference/digestif-drinks-france (drinking a small quantity...should indeed make you digest more easily)

Comment: grappa and limoncello are not marketed as digestives (source: me, as I'm Italian). Amaros like Jagermeister and similars are.

Comment: See also here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaro_(liqueur)

Comment: @JohnRhoades - Just never heard of those drinks as digestives anywhere, despite enjoying them for many years

Comment: @Sklivvz Grappa marketed as digestive: http://www.setteluna.com/digestivi.html Limoncello referred to as a digestive: http://www.walksofitaly.com/blog/food-and-wine/limoncello-lemon-liqueur-amalfi-coast-cinque-terre Perhaps they're wrong, or perhaps it varies depending on region or background?

Comment: The first link does not say what you claim!? The second link is OK, I can see how a lemon based drink could be seen as digestive - Still, the claim is way bigger for real (herb-based) amari like [1](http://www.averna.it/en/history.htm), [2](http://www.montenegro.it/eng/affissioni.htm), [3](http://www.amarolucano.it/lucano-nella-storia/comunicazione/comunicazione-1950/#!prettyPhoto)...

Comment: The main point is that the claim should be that amaros help digestion because they are herb-based infusions not because they contain alcohol.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've just been to Alsace where they drink Marc (similar to Grappa) and other fruit brandies (Eau de vie). Producers and restaurants claim they aid digestion, hence the question. I used Italian drinks as examples as that's what I'm more used to. Based on comments/answers it seems that bitters have a better chance of actually doing something to slightly help digestion than just high-alcohol drinks. And if they don't at least it's a good way to end a meal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe, maybe not...

Reference - [Effect on gastric function and symptoms of drinking wine, black tea, or schnapps with a Swiss cheese fondue: randomised controlled crossover trial](http://www.bmj.com/content/341/bmj.c6731) (BMJ)

Alcohol during or immediately after a heavy meal causes the stomach to empty more slowly.

[image]

It's not clear whether this effect is beneficial or not:

> Alcohol promotes gastric relaxation but delays gastric emptying. As a consequence, drinking white wine and schnapps with a Swiss cheese fondue may provide short term relief of postprandial dyspepsia; this may, however, come at the cost of more prolonged fullness (the feared “cheese baby” syndrome) and reflux.